# Bootstrapping issues in Chef

Tags: chef-solo, chef-infra

I have setup a basic infrastructure using chef. This includes a local chef server(ubuntu based), workstation and an ubuntu based server(to be used as the node). Please note that the entire infrastructure lies behind the firewall in my office network. And I have made necessary proxy settings for the servers to access the internet. 
So here is the problem - When I try to bootstrap the node using -

```
knife bootstrap <node's ip> --sudo -x <username> -P <password> -N "<name>"
```

i get the following error

```
<node's ip> --2014-02-19 10:47:10--  https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh
<node's ip> Resolving www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)... 184.106.28.91
<node's ip>1 Connecting to www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)|184.106.28.91|:443... failed:Connection refused.
<node's ip> bash: line 83: chef-client: command not found
```

I was not able to find a solution to this. However I came across the `knife[:bootstrap_proxy] = "http://username:password@proxyIP:port/"` setting that can be added to `knife.rb` . I did this (by entering my office proxy details) and then the connection during bootstrap was successfull and the chef client was downloaded on the node. However this setting only defines the proxy that should be used by the node. So, this led to the `http_proxy = "http://username:password@proxyIP:port/"` being set in `client.rb`. But because I have already made all the proxy settings in my server, the chef client failed to launch. So I manually removed the `http_proxy and https_proxy` settings from `client.rb` and ran the command `chef-client` which was then successful.
I have two questions -

1) why did `knife[:bootstrap_proxy] = "http://username:password@proxyIP:port/"` work? because it only defines the proxy that should be used by the node.

2) Also, alll the proxy setting for the node has already been done. I do not want any proxy settings in `client.rb`. How do I achieve this?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to your `client.rb` I'd suggest looking into https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/chef-client

It's a wrapper script for `client.rb`(s).

Not sure about your `knife[:bootstrap_proxy]` though. Ideally that cookbook should take care of it. If you are still stumpped you can run `chef-client -VV` and `knife -VV` to see exactly what it's doing.