# Open port 443 by adding a rule in iptables (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Im new to ubuntu and using ubuntu server 12.04.
When I run `nmap localhost` I get the following output :

```
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

This means that port 443(https) is closed. I want to open it.
So I did the following :

I ran the command

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

And to persist the changes I saved the file using `sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"`

and then I added the following lines to `etc/network/interfaces` :

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
post-down iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

After rebooting my system I ran `sudo iptables -L` and the line

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
```

was visible.

However now when I run `nmap localhost` I still dont see 443 as open.

Please help!

Comment: What server have you configured to listen on port 443?

Comment: This is _way_ off-topic for SO. Please delete and post on [sf].

Comment: Im trying to bootstrap this machine to a chef server. the chef server instructs this machine to download some software from www.opscode.com. When it tries to connect to www.opscode.com I get and error saying - <machine's IP> Connecting to www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)|184.106.28.91|:443... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: You can find the exact scenario [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871964/bootstrapping-issues-in-chef)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I bet you have nothing listening to port 443 on your host.  Try this: in one terminal run `sudo nc -lk 443` and then run your `nmap localhost`.  This may not have anything to do with an iptables firewall rule.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Any idea what the problem might be? why Am i getting Connecting to www.opscode.com (www.opscode.com)|184.106.28.91|:443... failed: Connection refused. ?

Comment: Sounds like you expect something, `https`, to be listening on port 443,so I would look at your web server's configuration and documentation.